# Looking for a way to check if a word is pronounceable

Tags: php, string, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measure the pronounceability of a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186213/measure-the-pronounceability-of-a-word)

There are a lot of pronounceable random password generators.
I am looking for the reverse.
I like to know if a given word is pronounceable.

Purpose:
I am looking for a new domain name, you probably have gone though this as well.

Comment: i don't think the `word` tag is intended for this :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the function [levenstein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) against a dictionary.

Additional regex patterns to check for overused vowels or repeated consonants after each other would also be of great help.

PS: This is not the real use of levenstein but I'm sure it might be of good use for this.

Just my idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are a *lot* of ways to approach this, but here's what I would use:

1) Get a dictionary like `/usr/share/dict/words`

2) Write a program that looks at each letter and figures out the odds of any letter following it. For example, it might find that an E has a 1% chance of being followed by an A, or that an X has a 5% chance of being followed by the end of the word.

This should let you generate things that are word-like, but not words themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I think language model probability can help you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model

Answer (score -1):

I go to the terminal (mac) and type in say.

Such as

Say Hello World!