# Is there any logic to validate whether a group of letters could be considered a phonetic word?

Tags: php, validation, cpu-word

Basically, if I'm given a random jumble of letters, I need to check to see if this could phonetically be considered a word.

I'm not looking to validate against a dictionary list, since I don't really care if the letters form an actual word or not.  I just need to determine whether or not those letters are in the correct format to be considered a word.

For example:

```
aaaaaa // Not valid, because there are no consonants
bbbbbb // Not valid, because no vowels
dogcat // Valid, even though it is not a word, because it phonetically makes what could be considered a word
dapmar // Valid, even though nothing about this is a word, it phonetically works
```

I realize there are going to be exceptions to almost any logic given, so this doesn't have to be an exact science, I would just like to catch the majority, so the most general logic would work for me.

I think it all boils down to whether or not a jumble of letters can be pronounced easily.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What about words like `ugh` or `oh` or `a`?

Comment: In what language?  Assuming English?

Comment: Wondering how many English words are composed entirely of vowels, or entirely of consonants

Comment: Turns out I needed to look for the pronounceability of a jumble of letters.  I ended up using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186213/measure-the-pronounceability-of-a-word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent letters to be repeated more than 3 times first, for example ccc will be invalid (or maybe you could do every letters except vowels so aaaaa, eeeee, uuuuu will be ok), then check all words from a list of existing words of your language only if you want to check something, but if you're generating a pronouncable word I don't think you'll need existing words.

Pleas also check this: [pronounceability algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874274/pronounceability-algorithm) , http://10000ideas.blogspot.fr/2011/07/what-makes-word-pronounceable.html  and this one : [Measure the pronounceability of a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186213/measure-the-pronounceability-of-a-word)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186213/measure-the-pronounceability-of-a-word worked for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For the amount of time and effort it would take to write code to logically check this, you'd be better off getting a file with as many English words as possible and putting them into an array. That would be your BEST logical check.

Comment: Thank you, but the text I am checking doesn't necessarily have to result in an actual word, just something that can phonetically be pronounced (ie, it **could** be a word)